# Convergence in mean square of function of Bernoulli

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am wondering if $Y_n$ converge in mean square:

$Y_n=2^nX_1X_2\cdots X_n$

where $X_k, k=1,2,\ldots,n$ is equi-probably i.i.d. Bernoulli random variable.

**Here is what I have tried:**

$E[Y_n^2]=E[(2^nX_1X_2\cdots X_n)^2]=4^nE[X_1^2X_2^2\cdots X_n^2]$

Obviously, $X_k$ is either $0$ or $1$, therefore:

$4^nE[X_1^2X_2^2\cdots X_n^2]=4^n(0^2(1-\frac{1}{2^n})+1^2(\frac{1}{2^n}))=2^n$

Above is because $X_1^2X_2^2\cdots X_n^2$ can only be either $1$ or $0$, and it is $1$ only when all $X_k^2$ is $1$.

since

$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n$ is not bounded, therefore, $Y_n$ does not converge in mean square.

I am wondering did I do it right? My sense is I did it wrong somewhere, yes?

Comment: Well, you need to specify whether or not the variables $\{X_i\}$ are mutually independent.

Comment: @Michael Why is that?

Comment: It would also help to know what you suspect the $Y_n$ variables are converging to.

Comment: Your calculation seems to implicitly assume mutual independence, since you used $Pr[X_1=X_2=...=X_n=1] = Pr[X_1=1]Pr[X_2=1]...Pr[X_n=1]=(1/2)^n$.  Without knowing the joint distribution, we cannot make such a calculation.

Comment: Yes, they are iid.

Comment: No.  Suppose $X_1=X_2=...=X_n$.  Then $Pr[X_1=X_2=...=X_n=1]=1/2$. So, dependence/independence has a huge affect on the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. They are iid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31292/discussion-between-michael-and-nick-x-tsui).